# create a schema for nested objects in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have data that looks like this:

```
{
name:'name'
email:'email'
password:'pass'
role:{checked: {'1' : true, '2': true ... any number of key value pairs}}}
}
```

How do I create mongoose schema for this kind of data
?

```
var CustomUserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: {
     checked: { type: Number, type: boolean }  //I need to define something like this here probably
  },
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String
});
```

How do I define the schema for this? Basically I am storing the checkbox values in role field.

Checkbox fields have their ng model set to `user.role.checked[$index]`

Comment: is your problem with not being able to store the role property? The rest looks fine

Comment: That's right. I don't know how to store role property. No problem with rest of the data